# Something is wrong, can somebody help me with INPUT in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, input

I am a beginner in python. This may seem very basic. I am using python 2.7

If I use input in python prompt, I get an error. I am typing this:

```
my_reply= input ("Enter your reply")
```

If I enter any letter/character, I get an error saying that `my_reply` is not defined. However, If I enter a number, there is no error.

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Try using `raw_input()` instead

Comment: The code you show is for Python 3, not 2.7.

Comment: You are reading the wrong documentation: [Python3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) vs [Python2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input). Python2:  Consider using the raw_input() function for general input from users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 2.7, input is actually trying to evaluate the "string" you pass to it. Therefore, if you were to input something like

```
Hello World
```

it would simply evaluate to the expression Hello World - not a string. This can be avoided by supplying correct python string:

```
'Hello World'
```

The real solution here is using `raw_input` function. `raw_input` does not try to evaluate the value and therefore, the first example would work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

In Python2, you should use `raw_input` rather than `input`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `raw_input` so Python won't evaluate your input as a string. It is then your responsibility to validate the input.